# Accessing a WCF Service secured by ACS from javascript

Tags: wcf, appcelerator-mobile, acs

I am looking to create a WCF (possibly WebApi) web service that sits on top of some of our existing code. Eventually this service will be used by external clients but we are going to start using it with our own mobile app.

As some clients will want to use Gmail and ADFS authentication it seems to make sense to use Azure ACS (this is where our webservices are hosted). However we won't need multiple providers for a while and we will start by using a custom STS that authenticates users against our existing authentication logic.

We already have a rough prototype of the above working using a MVC web application acting as the client.

My problem is how do I integrate this with a mobile application? It looks as if the mobile app will be written using AppCelerator which means I need to authenticate using javascript. We only want users to authenticate to our custom STS so would I need to use Active Authentication? I.e.

- Ask user to enter username and password
- Directly authenticate with custom STS and retrieve token
- Pass STS token to ACS and retrieve ACS token
- Pass ACS token to wcf service for each request.

I guess my questions are: am I on the right track and if so how would I achieve this in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to  support mobile devices, it is recommended to provide a web based login interface in your STS. In most cases, a mobile device will navigate to your STS’s sign in page in a web browser. After your STS authenticates the user, it sends claims to ACS. ACS in turn uses JavaScript notification to notify the host application. 
You can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WAZPlatformTrainingCourse_ACSAndWindowsPhone7 for a tutorial about working with ACS in Windows Phone. Similar process can be used for other mobile devices.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Although we decided to create a native app in the end, the link you provided pointed us in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to issue SAML over Https request. As a starting point Id suggest to look at Thinktecture IdentityServer sources by Dominick Baier. This will help to understand different strategies and how you can use em(there are some goodies for WebApi on Github also):
http://identityserver.codeplex.com/